# SE activity does not include Meta.SE

Tags: bug, meta, global-inbox, recent-activity

Currently, although the SE Inbox does include responses from Meta.SE the recent activity tab at SE does not include Meta.SE activity.

Comment: Careful, MSE is usually understood as math.SE. Meta will need its own abbreviation...

Comment: @vonbrand given that there are a number of other SE's whose name begin with "m", references to both meta.SE and math.SE should aim to type the extra three characters.

Comment: @vonbrand It could just be mSE vs. MSE.